# How to add TransferWise Borderless Account as a Bank Account in Paypal

Tags: bank-account, foreign-exchange, money-transfer, international-transfer, paypal

I want to withdraw my money in Paypal to TransferWise Borderless Account since the conversion rate offered by TransferWise is better than Paypal's.

I want to add it as a Bank Account in Paypal but I always get an error. Has anybody succeeded doing it? How?

Comment: [TransferWise FAQ](https://transferwise.com/help/article/2200390/creating-a-transfer/incompatible-accounts-and-currencies) which may explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've done this. Just added the borderless account into Paypal as a new bank account and the money has now showed up in my borderless account. I used the ACH Routing Number for my USD account.

Comment: Can you please give more details? I've tried the same but I always got errors. For example what is the bank name you used when adding a bank account to PayPal?

Comment: @AminahNuraini I have the same issue, how did you solve this ?

Comment: Use the ACH routing number for your USD account.  Paypal didn't ask me for a bank name.  Now to see if the test money appears in transerwise.